# Testing button state using JWebUnit

Tags: button, web-testing, ui-testing, jwebunit

Is it possible to test if a button is enabled or disabled(even if it is enabled/disabled using java script after few form actions) in the page using JWebUnit.

Comment: Please provide additional Information, such as source code and the point where you stuck during your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the element (button) by xpath locator strategy then you can use "getElementAttributeByXPath(String xpath, String attribute)" This will allow you to check the attribute of the object which will be enabled/disabled